# Filter values of a cck field with a view

Tags: views, entities

When I create a new node of a certain type, I would like to filter a certain field depending on a view. For example I would like to filter through the top 3 latest news stories (as the view will filter though a news story content type which will display the 3 latest news story only so the sort criteria would be by the date).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the latest 3:

1. Set the **Fields** you want to display, most likely Node: Title
2. Under **Basic Settings** set the limit to "3"
3. Add a **Sort Criteria** Node: Post date - ascending
4. Other **Filters** you'll want to add are: Node: Published - Yes & Node: Type

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for your reply

I have already configured the views with the relevant sorts and filters. I just need that view to show on a  CCK field on node edit. I was guessing the view can have a contextual filter of the NID but still cannot find a way to show it.

Thank you anyway!

Comment: She answered the question as you asked. Can you reframe the question with the results you are trying to achieve?